# Updating table where seen = 0 or select data

Tags: php, mysql

I have an alert menu to show new things for users. It is a PHP system like ebay.

So I have sell table:

```
id
seller
customer
product_name
date
```

What I want is to show for each user an menu with alerts with new sells. For this too work I can:

Method 1:

Add `SEEN` column in sell table, set it as 0 on insert, and when `USER` clicks in alert menu it will scan table to set `SEEN` as 1.

```
update sell set seen = 1 where seen = 0 and seller = ?
```

Method 2:

record last time(date) user clicks on alert menu, then select new alerts `where date > last_date_click`:

```
select * from sell where date > $last_date_click and seller = ?
```

So, my question is, which one should I use in this case and why?

Comment: You posted the same question last night and it was put on hold. Kindly avoid that.

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari thank you for remember me! but now I change my question...

Comment: @Livia First you need to maintain last click of each user.

Comment: You maybe want to look into something like https://getstream.io/docs/ it's a feed service which could help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

this method wont work as you really want. 
In your method you should create new table that contains id,productID,userseenID, than you doing your check if the buyer already get inside the product.
Of course that you have to update it when im as user get inside an item you should check if userseenID exist in productID, if not than create one.
By the way, you can add time(), to know exactly when and which user visit the item.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question Below method is useful as it is better to have select query instead of multiple update queries.

method 2:

record last time(date) user clicks on alert menu, than select new alerts where date > last_date_click:

```
select * from sell where date > $last_date_click and seller = ?
```

Comment: yes... my real problem with date is when I think about daylight saving time, server can change the time... so maybe alerts can stop or getting crazy.

Answer (score 0):

The question comes under the category of *too broad* but since you are eager to know, the way I see it, A `SELECT` as such would be must faster as it involves only searching and fetching apart from the `UPDATE` one which would need to search and as well as update!

PS. There are alot of people with knowledge greater than just this. I hope  [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar), [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) or someone else looks into this for deeper analysis. cheers.

```
select * from sell where date > $last_date_click and seller = ?
```

Comment: thank you friend! my problem with date is that can get crazy on time changes, for example, DST, server time change... but if it is faster I think it is really the best way!

Comment: What better way than to _test and check yourself_ starting off with a little sample data? You're welcome `:-)` Stay safe and keep coding! cheers